# access vba: strange behaviour assigning onMouseMove

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am having a problem with assigning OnMouseMove events dynamically.

In a report I have several hundred buttons which I assign an OnClick event to. This event opens another report by using a conditional WHERE in the call.
I do that by extracting the name of the Button (which includes its number), extracting that number and giving it as an argument to a function.
This works well and the correct report opens. I thought, without checking, that the argument is given correctly.

It works as follows:

In an Init Function of the report I have

```
 For Each ctl In Me.Controls
If ctl.ControlType = acCommandButton Then
nSekNr = ParseNumber(ctl.Name, 6)
  ctl.OnClick = "=MapButtonClick('" & sBtnName & "', '" & nSekNr & "')"
[...]
```

The ParseNumber function just includes

```
ParseNumber = Right(ctlName, (Len(ctlName) - z))
```

Then, I have my click function as follows

```
Public Function MapButtonClick(ByVal sBtnName As String, ByVal nSekNr As Byte)
DoCmd.Minimize
DoCmd.Close acReport, "repSektion"
DoCmd.OpenReport "repSektion", acViewPreview, , "[SekID] = " & nSekNr
End Function
```

This works and opens the correct report when I click on each button.
(yes I know one parameter is not needed, it's just a carryover from something else I was trying)

Now: I want to show the number of the button in the report using a label and the OnMouseMove so the user can see the section id before he clicks the button.

Trouble is, when I duplicate my function, Access does not seem to send the nSekNr variable as an argument.
I do this by using a new function

```
Public Function MapButtonShowID(sBtnName As String, nSekNr As Integer)
Me.sekshow.Visible = True
Me.sekshow.Caption = "Sektion: " & sSekNr
End Function
```

In which sekshow is an empty label.
I call this right underneath the init of the click event like so

```
 For Each ctl In Me.Controls
If ctl.ControlType = acCommandButton Then
nSekNr = ParseNumber(ctl.Name, 6)
  ctl.OnClick = "=MapButtonClick('" & sBtnName & "', '" & nSekNr & "')"
 ctl.OnMouseMove = "=MapButtonShowId('" & sBtnName & "', '" & nSekNr & "')"
[...]
```

This gives me an empty "Sektion: " without the number on the report.

Now begins the strange thing:
I checked if the nSekNr is even correctly given to either function by adding a MsbBox. I mean surely if the click event works then it is because the correct nSekNr is given. Turns out neither function even recieves the variable - it is empty!

But why then does my click event work? The report in question doesn't really have any internal filtering, it is just a basic report that shows some data.

I am lost.

Assigning the events by hand is pretty much not an option because there are so many.

Maybe there is a way to do this correctly, and figure out why that click event even works if the argument is given as empty?

Comment: If the ctl.Name is a number only, try `CInt(ctl.Name)`. In your handler assingment you have `nSekNr` between quotes (send it as string?) What happens if you remove the quotes and send `nSekNr` as integer?

Comment: The name includes an additional identified ("SekButtonA-D") which I also parse - didn't include that in the sample.  Removing the quotes of nSekNr does not change the outcome. For some reason the argument is not given to the function. I will now investigate if the nSekNr variable is correctly parsed in the first place.

Comment: Okay so the SekBtNr is and its name is correctly parsed in the init function. Additionally the string for the event procedure is set up correctly. It seems there is an error when assigning the argument, which is given as empty. HOWEVER, the (static) string sBtnName IS indeed given correctly. What the hell. I will now try to give the complete ctl.Name to the function and parse it in the MapButtonShowID function instead of the init function.

Answer (score 0):

The mystery is solved, it was a typo.
Sorry for wasting your time but the function works as intended if someone looks to assign event procedures dynamically for each control of a certain type in a report. This probably needs Access 2010 though

Comment: I just made a quick test in access 2010, and the principle works. However if for some reason your parsing fails and `nSekNr` is empty, you will get one of those access dialogs popping up `The Expression OnClick you entered as the event property... blah blah`.